# PHP Error in SQL syntax MYSQLi

Tags: php, mysql

My SQL Query looks completely fine but I keep getting the same error message.

What i want to do is a simple search it will look inside the data table which holds xml for a match.

[image]

**The error**

Fatal error: Problem preparing query (SELECT * FROM propertie_ids WHERE data LIKE '%test%' ) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''%test%'

**Current Code**

```
    $trimmed = "test";

    $results = $this->db->rawQuery("SELECT * FROM propertie_ids WHERE data LIKE %$trimmed%");
```

[My Database class](https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class)

Comment: `LIKE CONCAT('%', $trimmed, '%')` -- try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
<?php
$trimmed = "test";
$results = $this->db->rawQuery("SELECT * FROM propertie_ids WHERE data LIKE ".'%'.$trimmed.'%'."");
```

Found this from your DB Class. You can try this.

```
<?php
$trimmed = array('%test%');
$results = $this->db->rawQuery("SELECT * FROM propertie_ids WHERE data LIKE ?",$trimmed);
print_r($results);
```

Comment: Still same error bro, http://www.hgh.digibug-dev.co.uk/backup/feed/show_properties.php Uploaded here.

Answer (score 1):

Use a parameterized query and let the DB class worry about quoting and such.  It's more likely to get that stuff right.

```
$trimmed = 'test';

$results = $this->db->rawQuery(
    'SELECT * FROM propertie_ids WHERE data LIKE ?',
    array("%$trimmed%")
);
```